# Why should I join USENIX and SAGE?

Tags: documentation

I've recently discovered some documentation on sage.org website that would be of interest and great help to me. But in order to access to it I have to register with USENIX. Now since I'm from Europe and the organization is very US based I cant see a reason to pay a sizable membership fee - I will not benefit from most offers.

Now the question in two parts:

1. Can anyone suggest how do I explain to my employer (based on what I stated above) why he has to pay for my membership?
2. Anyone know of a LEGAL way to get my hands on that SAGE documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answer your own question: 1) they have documentation which would be of interest and great help to you, and 2) become a member and there you go.